# javascript breaking when adding this code

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript isn't my strongest skill, but I'll do my best to explain, so here it goes. I had someone create a slideup menu on my website and im also using jplayer music player.

Now everything works fine until I add this script at the top. For some reason it stops the slideup from working. This is the script that stops the slideup.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If someone could tell me what im doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you already have a jquery reference in your code that your menu uses? If you do, then you might have a version mismatch. You only need one jquery reference, and adding two of different versions can cause problems. Check your code for jquery references, and check your console.

Comment: It worries me that you are using different kind of apostrophes while JavaScript only accepts single apostrophe (') and double quotation mark (")

Answer (score 1):

Try using this to include your jQuery: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

That is taken from the jplayer demo page at http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-video/ - line 22

Comment: Yes! Maybe it resolves the issue. Just use:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Will you post your site's domain?  Without that its just guesswork

Comment: does this help? im getting this error: 

 TypeError: jq(...).jqEasyPanel is not a function

Comment: If your site isn't live, or you don't want to put your site live, just use a demo.mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

you are not importing jQuery correctly. After consulting Google HOsted Libraries page (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=es&csw=1#jquery) seems that the version to be imported should be 1.7.0 (Three digits, not two), try it!

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just copy paste the link in the OP's code into your browser to see if it works, and loh and behold, it does.

Comment: Ouch! If you open the JS conosle (F12 > Console) Do you see any error?

Comment: Im getting this TypeError: jq(...).jqEasyPanel is not a function

Comment: Are you using this plugin? http://www.jqeasy.com/ If yes, I downloaded the code and I checked that it is running with jQuery 1.4.2 (a bit old) Probably you have a jQuery version conflict. How are you importing this library??

Comment: Anyway, I recommend you to use other jQuery library for the slider... Just typing "jQuery slider" in Google there are lots of them

Comment: @RafaRomero I did some searching and found this in my functions:

    `wp_enqueue_script( 'footer-easypanel-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.jqEasyPanel.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );`

Would it have anything to do with the problem?